# Check if input already exists in textfile with Java

Tags: java, input

I want to create a small project where a name can be inserted and that is saved with the data of the input in a textfile. 
Additionally it should check,  if this name is already in the document and if so, there should be an alert and the name should not be added.

The code below is how I add the names to the textfile.

```
else if (i == 1) {  
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Surname: ");
    surname = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("First name: ");
    firstname = input.nextLine();

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));


    File file = new File("C://Users/Prakt1/Desktop/projektverwaltung.txt");
    String content = ("Surname " + (surname) + LINE_SEPARATOR + "First name: " + (firstname) + LINE_SEPARATOR + "Added: " +
    (sdf.format(date)) + LINE_SEPARATOR);

    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users/Prakt1/Desktop/projektverwaltung.txt", true)))) {
       out.println(content);          
    }catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I do this in Java without jQuery/JavaScript?

Thank you for you help,
Chris

Comment: you will need to open the file (FileReader or other inputstream) and compare the contents line by line

Comment: I'm interested to know how you'd do it *with* jQuery/JavaScript!

Comment: It was a serious request for his existing code in jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: Evaluating javascript inside java code is generally bad idea, as long as you can achive better results using Java.

Comment: I love how tone gets lost completely on the Internet.

Comment: I have no idea about JavaScript, sorry for the missunderstanding.

Comment: @user3013909 No, you're fine. I don't appreciate people being Internet police when I'm just having a minor chuckle. There's an answer for you below, let me know what you think by leaving a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution: First build the name string, then read the file and check if it is in there. If it is alert, otherwise, perform your insert

```
// Build the string
String content = ("Surname " + (surname) + LINE_SEPARATOR + "First name: " + (firstname);

// Read all contents into a String
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C://Users/Prakt1/Desktop/projektverwaltung.txt"));
String s = new String(bytes);

// Check if the name is contained
if(s.indexOf(content) != -1){
     System.out.println("Name already present!");
} else {
     ... // Do your usual insertion
}
```

Note that you must specify an encoding in the `new String` constructor, unless your file uses your platform's default encoding. For example, it might look like this for UTF8:

```
String s = new String(bytes,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Also note that this approach reads the file into memory thoroughly. Thus, if you have a really huge file (>50 MB) that would yield an `OutOfMemory` error upon reading, you should rather use a `BufferedReader` and read the file line by line.

Comment: lets hope the size of file is small

Comment: If it's small wouldn't you just read it into memory then? The file operations are going to be slower with little to be gained from a small text file in terms of saved space. @ScaryWombat

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Well, yes :). I will add a hint

Comment: The file is not very big so that shouldn´t be an issue. It justs a few inputs so that I can learn and practive Java. Eclipse suggested to add a try catch for "Read all content into a Sting. After adding it it works how I want it :) Thank you all for the help and sorry the slight missunderstanding with JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do this like sample:

you have to follow these steps:

1. Read file till end
2. match ceriteria
3. if not found till end of file
4. append it / else already exist

   ```
   public void appendFile(String surName, String firstName){
   File file = new File("C:/robots.txt");
       FileInputStream fis = null;
       try {
           fis = new FileInputStream(file);
           String line = reader.readLine();
           boolean isFound = false;
           while(line != null){
               System.out.println(line);
                  // or the match you want to e.g. surname
               if(line.equals(surName)){
                   isFound = true;
                   break;
               }
               line = reader.readLine();
           }
           //This is End of File
           if(!isFound)}{
               //Not in file append it at the end of file
           }else{
               //Already exist in file
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           try {
               if (fis != null)
                   fis.close();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I wish I could give you half-a-vote, I think it would be better to break out of the while loop when it is found

Comment: Rather use a `try` with resource statement. I guess OP already uses at least Java7.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest streaming line by line to reduce the memory footprint. This method does no validation and assumes that your file is formatted the way you suggested in your code.

```
try( FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(
        "C://Users/Prakt1/Desktop/projektverwaltung.txt" );
     BufferedReader reader  = new BufferedReader( fileReader ) )
{
    String line = null;
    String currentSurname = null;
    String currentFirstName = null;
    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )
    {
        if( line.startsWith( "Surname " ) )
        {
            currentSurname = line.substring( "Surname ".length() );
        }
        else if( line.startsWith( "First name: " ) )
        {
            currentFirstName = line.substring( "First name: ".length() );
        }
        else
        {
            if( currentSurname != null &&
                currentFirstName != null &&
                currentSurname.equals( surname ) &&
                currentFirstName.equals( firstName ) )
            {
                System.out.println( "Name already in file." );
                break;
            }
            currentSurname = null;
            currentFirstName = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not try this out, but as far as I understand the code and your comment, this does not work when I have text before the name list. Apparently this is the case for me. But thanks for the help!

Comment: I've made an edit so it should work as long as those three lines (surname, first name and added) occur together. If your file gets large, be sure to give it a try!